# 3-day sum column DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with a large dataset and very new to Python coding.

I want a new column that calculates the sum total difference in sales for every 3-day period.

For example, in the dataset below, the **3-day sum total difference** between the 01-01-2020 and 03-01-2020 would be **200** - **100** = *100* (or 03-01-2020 minus 01-01-2020). Between 02-01-2020 and 04-01-2020 would be **300** - **200** = **100**.

Because my original dataset is massive, I have hundreds of rows to iterate over. So I was thinking of writing a for-loop, indexing values using range, so that after generating the sum it pushes the indexing up a notch to calculate the next but I can't put my thinking to code.

I've found other questions relating to rolling sum, but it's not quite what I need.

**Current output:**

| Date | Business | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2020 | A | 100 |
| 02-01-2020 | A | 200 |
| 03-01-2020 | A | 200 |
| 04-01-2020 | A | 300 |
| 05-01-2020 | A | 200 |
| 06-01-2020 | A | 100 |
| 07-01-2020 | A | 200 |

**Expected output**

| Date | Business | Sales | 3-day sum diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2020 | A | 100 | - |
| 02-01-2020 | A | 200 | - |
| 03-01-2020 | A | 200 | 100 |
| 04-01-2020 | A | 300 | 100 |
| 05-01-2020 | A | 400 | 200 |
| 06-01-2020 | A | 100 | -200 |
| 07-01-2020 | A | 200 | -200 |

Comment: Do you always have all the consecutive dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add 2 days to `Date`, create `MultiIndex Series` and substract, last create new column by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)

s = df.set_index(['Date','Business'])['Sales']
s1 = s.rename(lambda x: x + pd.Timedelta(2, unit='d'), level=0)

df = df.join(s.sub(s1).rename('3-day sum diff'), on=['Date','Business'])
print (df)
        Date Business  Sales  3-day sum diff
0 2020-01-01        A    100             NaN
1 2020-01-02        A    200             NaN
2 2020-01-03        A    200           100.0
3 2020-01-04        A    300           100.0
4 2020-01-05        A    200             0.0
5 2020-01-06        A    100          -200.0
6 2020-01-07        A    200             0.0
```

Or use left join with `merge` and substract columns:

```
df = df.merge(df.assign(Date = df['Date'].add(pd.Timedelta(2, unit='d'))), 
              how='left', 
              on=['Date','Business'])

df['3-day sum diff'] = df['Sales_x'].sub(df['Sales_y'])
print (df)
        Date Business  Sales_x  Sales_y  3-day sum diff
0 2020-01-01        A      100      NaN             NaN
1 2020-01-02        A      200      NaN             NaN
2 2020-01-03        A      200    100.0           100.0
3 2020-01-04        A      300    200.0           100.0
4 2020-01-05        A      200    200.0             0.0
5 2020-01-06        A      100    300.0          -200.0
6 2020-01-07        A      200    200.0             0.0
```